# Why is number of open files limited in Linux?

Tags: open-files, limit

Right now, I know how to:

- find open files limit per process: `ulimit -n`
- count all opened files by all processes: `lsof | wc -l`
- get maximum allowed number of open files: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

My question is: Why is there a limit of open files in Linux?

Comment: @Rob Googled a little and find that it's a [fork bomb](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-bash-fork-bomb/), can it be used to explain open file limit?

Comment: Well, process limits and file limits are important so things like fork bombs don't break a server/computer for all users, only the user that does it and only temporarily. Otherwise, someone on a shared server could set off a forkbomb and completely knock it down for all users, not just themselves.

Comment: Nice one summing up some very useful commands! :+1:

Comment: @Rob, a fork bomb doesn't have anything to do with it since the file limit is per process and each time you fork it does not open a new file handle.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The reason is that the operating system needs memory to manage each open file, and memory is a limited resource - especially on embedded systems.

As root user you can change the maximum of the open files count per process (via `ulimit -n`) and per system (e.g. `echo 800000 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`).

Comment: There is also a security reason : if there were no limits, a userland software would be able to create files endlessly until the server goes down.

Comment: @Coren The here discussed limits are only for the count of open file handlers. As a program can also close file handlers, it could create as many files and as big as it want, until all available disk space is full. To prevent this, you can use disk quotas or separated partitions. You are true in the sense, that one aspect of security is preventing resource exhaustion - and for this there are limits.

Comment: @jofel Thanks. I guess that opened file handles are represented by instances of [struct file](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32.28/include/linux/fs.h#L911), and size of this struct is quite small (bytes level), so can I set `/.../file-max` with a quite big value as long as memory is not used up?

Comment: @xanpeng I am not a kernel expert, but as far as I can see, the default for `file-max` seems to be RAM size divided by 10k. As the real memory used per file handler should  be much smaller (size of `struct file` plus some driver dependent memory), this seems a quite conservative limit.

Comment: The max you can set it to is 2^63-1: `echo 9223372036854775807 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`. Don't know why Linux is using signed integers.

Answer (score 88):

Please note that `lsof | wc -l` sums up a lot of duplicated entries (forked processes can share file handles etc). That number could be much higher than the limit set in `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`.

To get the current number of open files from the Linux kernel's point of view, do this:

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`

Example: This server has 40096 out of max 65536 open files, although lsof reports a much larger number:

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
65536
# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr 
40096   0       65536
# lsof | wc -l
521504
```

Comment: As `lsof` will report many files twice or more, such as `/dev/null`, you can try a best guess with: `lsof|awk '{print $9}'|sort|uniq|wc -l`

Comment: you may use `lsof|awk  '!a[$NF]++{c++}END{print c}'` to get the non-duplicate count of open files.

Comment: Very old question but i have bene looking into these settings on my server and lsof | wc -l give 40,000 while file-nr says 2300 - is that discrepancy normal?

Answer (score 25):

I think it's largely for historical reasons.

A Unix file descriptor is a small `int` value, returned by functions like `open` and `creat`, and passed to `read`, `write`, `close`, and so forth.

At least in early versions of Unix, a file descriptor was simply an index into a fixed-size per-process array of structures, where each structure contains information about an open file.  If I recall correctly, some early systems limited the size of this table to 20 or so.

More modern systems have higher limits, but have kept the same general scheme, largely out of inertia.

Comment: 20 was the Solaris limit for C language FILE data structures. The file handle count was always larger.

Comment: @Lothar: Interesting. I wonder why the limits would differ. Given the `fileno` and `fdopen` functions I'd expect them to be nearly interchangeable.

Comment: A unix file is more than just the file handle (int) returned. There are disk buffers, and a file control block that defines the current file offset, file owner, permissions, inode, etc.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: Yes, of course. But most of that information has to be stored whether a file is accessed via an `int` descriptor or a `FILE*`. If you have more than 20 files open via `open()`, would `fdopen()` fail?